# How to compute image of boolean function

Tags: lo.logic, algorithms

I have a function $F: \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$. Denote by $F_i : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ the $i$th component. I assume that for each $i$, $F_i$ can be written as conjunction of at most $n$ propositional literals (i.e. propositional variables or negated propositional variables). These formulas are known.

I am interested in obtaining the image $F(\{0,1\}^n)$ or it's complement from the syntax of the $F_i$ formulas, which I hope would be faster than enumerating the whole domain.

EDIT: Computing only $|F(\{0,1\}^n)|$ would be also useful to me.

Could anyone give me a hint how to approach such problem?

Comment: Doesn't this include SAT (the prototypical NP-complete problem) as a special case?

Comment: I was considering that, was unable to prove anything in this regard, but I thik not: The syntax here is very restricted, in contrast to SAT.

Comment: The problem “given $F$ (described by conjunctions of literals as in the question), is $\vec0\in F(\{0,1\}^n)$?” is exactly SAT.

Comment: But the inclusion goes other way than what @FedericoPoloni suggests, no? It can be solved as a SAT, yes,but SAT in general is not a special case of this.

Comment: No. The problem in my comment is equivalent to SAT, the reduction being just to reinterpret all clauses as conjunctions.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Actually I think it is SAT in [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form), which is a variant. So if I am not mistaken the question to ask is "is $F(\{0,1\}^n)=\{\vec{1}\}$?"

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I’m sorry, but I can’t figure out your comment. When you say “it is SAT ...”, what do you mean by *it*? When you write “question to ask”, are you suggesting that the OP should ask that question, that it is somehow relevant to my comment, or something else? I’m not even sure if you agree or disagree with my comment.

Comment: $F(\{0,1\}^n)=\{\vec1\}$ is trivially testable in polynomial time, as it is true only if every $F_i$ is defined as the empty conjunction.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yup -- you are correct, sorry, I had a negation too much in my head. :) I agree 100% with what you say regarding this problem.